# How to modify a 'value' prop in VueJS before `$emit('input')` finishes updating it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I have a question about creating VueJS components that are usable with `v-model` which utilise underlying `value` prop and `$emit('input', newVal)`.

```js
props: {
  value: Array
},
methods: {
  moveIdToIndex (id, newIndex) {
    const newArrayHead = this.value
      .slice(0, newIndex)
      .filter(_id => _id !== id)
    const newArrayTail = this.value
      .slice(newIndex)
      .filter(_id => _id !== id)
    const newArray = [...newArrayHead, id, ...newArrayTail]
    return this.updateArray(newArray)
  },
  updateArray (newArray) {
    this.$emit('input', newArray)
  }
}
```

In the above code sample, if I do two modifications in quick succession, they will both be executed onto the "old array" (the non-modified `value` prop).

```js
moveIdToIndex('a', 4)
moveIdToIndex('b', 2)
```

In other words, I need to wait for the `value` to be updated via the `$emit('input')` in order for the second call to `moveIdToIndex` to use that already modified array.

#### Bad solution 1

One workaround is changing `updateArray` to:

```js
  updateArray (newArray) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.$emit('input', newArray)
      this.$nextTick(resolve)
    })
  }
```

and execute like so:

```
await moveIdToIndex('a', 4)
moveIdToIndex('b', 2)
```

But I do not want to do this, because I need to execute this action on an array of Ids and move them all to different locations at the same time. And `await`ing would greatly reduce performance.

#### Bad solution 2

A much better solution I found is to just do this:

```js
  updateArray (newArray) {
    this.value = newArray
    this.$emit('input', newArray)
  }
```

Then I don't need to wait for the `$emit` to complete at all.

However, in this case, VueJS gives a console error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"

Does anyone have any better solution?

Comment: Are you emitting the newArray to just update the prop from parent scope or you actually need the newArray outside the component.

Comment: I actually need the `newArray` in the parent scope as well. It's basically an array of IDs to populate a list. Other parts in my app sync this array to a DB or there might be a modification to this array outside of my child component that uses it via `v-model`.

BTW, thanks for the upvote!! 

Comment: Is the order of the update important? And I didn't upvote 

Comment: Yes, because each call changes the order of the ids. The next call should change the order based on the previous change to the order. Deferring the emit to the last is change is no problem, but i'd just have to rewrite moveToIndex to support an array of ids and indexes which only calls updateArray once. I guess that's solution as well but quite annoying XD (your up vote much appreciated! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. These are your options as far as I understand your use case and application.

First of all, don't mutate the props directly save the props internally and then modify that value.

```
props: {
  value: Array
},
data() {
  return {
    val: this.value
  }
}
```

If the next modification to the array is dependent on the previous modification to the array you can't perform them simultaneously. But you need it to happen fairly quickly ( i will assume that you want the user to feel that it's happening quickly ). What you can do is perform the modification on the `val` inside the component and not make it dependent on the prop. The `val` variable is only initialized when the component is mounted. This way you can modify the data instantly in the UI and let the database update in the background.

In other words, your complete solution would look like this:

```js
props: {
  value: Array
},
data () {
  return {val: this.value}
},
methods: {
  moveIdToIndex (id, newIndex) {
    const newArrayHead = this.val
      .slice(0, newIndex)
      .filter(_id => _id !== id)
    const newArrayTail = this.val
      .slice(newIndex)
      .filter(_id => _id !== id)
    const newArray = [...newArrayHead, id, ...newArrayTail]
    return this.updateArray(newArray)
  },
  updateArray (newArray) {
    this.val = newArray
    this.$emit('input', newArray)
  }
}
```

This solution fixes your problem and allows you to execute `moveIdToIndex` in quick succession without having to await anything.

Now if the array is used in many places in the application next best thing would be to move it to a store and use it as a single point of truth and update that and use that to update your component. Your state will update quickly not simultaneously and then defer the update to the database for a suitable time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Using `val` instead of `value` internally is probably better, but how then do I `$emit('input', newArray)` in this case?
(PS on your advice to use a store: The dev that uses my component will probably save this "array" he passes into `v-model` into a store regardlessly. My use case is more about how to best use and modify this `value` internally, which I think you answer pretty good.)

Comment: If you could edit your answer and add when to call `$emit('input', newArray)` after multiple fast calls to `moveIdToIndex` I'll mark it correct!

Comment: you can still emit the ``val`` . Currently, you are dependent on the prop for the state of the array, so you modify the array then emit it then it gets updated in the database then the prop in the parent gets updated then depending on that the child prop is updated which is then used to perform next modification to the array which causes the delay. By referring to internal ``val`` and making it independent of the prop will allow you to update the UI quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Dimensionless Your answer allowed me to find my solution. I have edited your answer to be more complete. I much appreciate your upvote.

Comment: Well much appreciated. And once again I didn't upvote but since you keep thanking me I did it now 

Answer (score 0):

1. `Emit` a message to the parent to change the prop.
2. Put a `watcher` on the prop (in the child) and put your code to use the new value there.

This keeps the child from mutating the data it does not own, and allows it to avoid using `nextTick`.  Now your code is asynchronous and reactive, without relying on non-deterministic delays.

Answer (score 0):

How about making copy of the `value` ?

```
moveIdToIndex (id, newIndex) {
    const valueCopy = [...this.value]
    const newArrayHead = this.valueCopy
      .slice(0, newIndex)
      .filter(_id => _id !== id)
    const newArrayTail = this.valueCopy
      .slice(newIndex)
      .filter(_id => _id !== id)
    const newArray = [...newArrayHead, id, ...newArrayTail]
    return this.updateArray(newArray)
```